# How to display the "Inf" label completly using ggplot2？

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, infinite

When I plot a line with infinity value using ggplot2 package, the label of it can not be display completely, even though I use a big "nudge_y" argument. A manual text can get the result, but it is not my answer.
How to display it completely?

```
x=seq(1,3,1)
y=c(1/3,Inf,3/3)
dt=data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=round(y,2))
ggplot(dt)+geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y))+
     geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y,label=z))
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ggrepel` package can achieve your goal as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

x = seq(1,3,1)
y = c(1/3,Inf,3/3)
dt = data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=round(y,2))

ggplot(dt, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
 geom_line()+
 geom_label_repel(aes(label=z), nudge_x = .05)
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Make your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` to show the part that is clipped beyond the plot area.

[image]